# Wrapped component not re-rendering in HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When init my app, my component first shows Preloader, then the HOC makes a request to the server and updates the data. But for some reason it does not re-rendering the component.

HOC:

```
export default function withData(WrappedComponent}) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                data: null
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            if (this.state.data === null) {
                Upload(location.origin + location.pathname).then(data => {
                    this.setState({data});
                });
            }
        }

        render() {
            console.log(1, this.state.data);

            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.data}/>;
        }
    };
}
```

Wrapped Component

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(2, props.data);

        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.data === null) {
            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        return <div>Done</div>;
    }
}

export default withData(Component);
```

When I run in the console, I see:

```
1 null
2 null
1 {.....}
```

The second time the Сomponent is not re-rendered

Comment: Are you sure that any data is coming back from the request? Where is location object coming from? And what does this return? location.origin + location.pathname

Comment: Put a console.log(this.props.data) in render() of Component and see the value?

Comment: @paruchuri-p, yes, I sure

Comment: @paruchuri-p, thank. My carelessness. Really needed to read props, not state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set data into your component's state when it first instantiates, in your constructor.

Don't copy it into state. Simply read `this.props.data` instead.

Comment: Thank. My carelessness. Really needed to read props, not state

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович you should click the empty check mark next to the right answer to help others find it, not answer your own questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem.

Thanks to the community for their help.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.data === null) {
            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        return <div>Done</div>;
    }
}

export default withData(Component);
```